# Securing a webpage for a short time period

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis-7.5, token

I need to create a webpage for a specific customer to use only during certain time frames.

I would like to make this page as secure as possible, by not allowing anybody else to see this page during this time frame. I would also like to make it as easy as possible for this customer to open this page.

My thinking is:

1. Open time frame
2. Send customer link via email
3. Email contains passcode to use to enter the page
4. After task is complete or time frame expires, the passcode also expires

To me, this seems pretty secure.

My concerns are:

- The customer forwarding the email (I don't see why they would do this, so may be a mute point)
- There is an inherent flaw in my thinking that I am not aware of.

The time frame is kept in a database. Each user action will have the passcode checked against the time frame to ensure that it is valid.

**Is this method secure, within a reasonable degree, or is there a better way that you know of, or an existing technology that deals with this problem already?**

Answer (score 1):

As i gather, you want to limit access to third-parties as much as possible. i think you'd want something login-based - have a simple registration procedure with which you can connect the email to a user, let the client choose their own password, give the user rights to access the page, share the link (either use encryption with email or do it with the user account), restrict multiple sessions. Once the client has the information, you can't really ensure that they don't misuse it..